# Async function confusion for parallelism

Tags: c#, task

I write the sample code based on the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

I think when TestAsync Task runs, the "Logic A" will be printed and then with the "await" keyword "Logic C" be printed.

But it actually runs just like a synchronized way, print "Logic C" then "Logic A"

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestAll();
    }

    static async void TestAll()
    {
        var y = TestAsync();

        // I want to do other jobs before task y finish
        Console.WriteLine("Logic A");

        int value = await y;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Task<int> TestAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
            ;
        Console.WriteLine("Logic C");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

But why print Logic C then Logic A ?

[image]

Thanks the answers, then another question:
I expect "Logic B" --> "Logic A" --> "Logic C" --> "1"

But it actually only prints "Logic B" --> "Logic A" and finished.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestAll();
    }

    static async void TestAll()
    {
        var y = TestAsync();

        // I want to do other jobs before task y finish
        Console.WriteLine("Logic A");

        // delete this line will be correct, but I don't know why
        int value = await y;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<int> TestAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Logic B");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Logic C");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, check my updated answer

Comment: sure, thanks! I understand it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, the output indicates the synchronous processing, because it actually is a synchronous processing. 
 Defining Task does not mean asynchronous processing. There is no new Task creation, you only wrapped code to Task, but you did not create a new one.

If you want to test async processing, you should modify your method:

```
private Task<int> TestAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
            ;
        Console.WriteLine("Logic C");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });
}
```

To answer your another question:


You don't have desired output because your Main method is not waiting for asynchronous operation to finish. So as a execution in method `TestAll` goes to `int value = await y;` the main method will continue and will finish gracefully.


Update your Main method to wait for async task and you will get desired output:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   TestAll().Wait();
}
```

But look at `synchronously waiting on asynchronous task` problem. It is related to context threads (UI thread, ASP context thread,...) so it should be safe with Console app, but always good to know `what is behind`.

Comment: You'd want to remove the `async` modifier in the method declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now !